# Touchpad two fingers detected as double tap

Tags: touchpad, scrolling, gestures, tap-to-click

Using the synaptics driver on Xorg (I have not tested Wayland/libinput), if I put two fingers on the touchpad it often detects it as a double tap (I guess because there is a very short delay between the first finger and the second one), so if I want to scroll I get a drag'n'drop instead.
I've tried changing almost all the options in the .conf file but I can't get rid of this problem: any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the following Ubuntu doc it will show and go over the different touchpad settings and allow you if chosen to disable the two finder double click: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/TouchpadSupport

Comment: I need the double tap, unfortunately...